Why is using a custom name tag for my Docker image and pushing to ECR not working from EC2 CLI?
I am trying to push from EC2 to private ECR. The official instructions say:
Retrieve an authentication token and authenticate your Docker client to your registry.
Use the AWS CLI:

aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 025416187662.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Note: If you receive an error using the AWS CLI, make sure that you have the latest version of the AWS CLI and Docker installed.
Build your Docker image using the following command. For information on building a Docker file from scratch see the instructions here . You can skip this step if your image is already built:

docker build -t redpanda-private-prod .
After the build completes, tag your image so you can push the image to this repository:

docker tag redpanda-private-prod:latest 025416187662.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/redpanda-private-prod:latest
Run the following command to push this image to your newly created AWS repository:

docker push 025416187662.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/redpanda-private-prod:latest

However I already built image with docker build -it r3:xx (skipping step with build above).
Then I just tag r3:xx with full name:
docker tag r3:xx 025416187662.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/r3:xx

then pushing it does not work:
docker push 025416187662.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/r3:xx

Why is this error message generated?
The push refers to repository [025416187662.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/r3]
f6a496422c6e: Preparing 
2a228f483135: Preparing 
82b7b3ada751: Preparing 
ee5c08f2b2b8: Preparing 
b450bdba9f84: Preparing 
937886fc1a47: Waiting 
c8f253aef560: Waiting 
a483da8ab3e9: Waiting 
name unknown: The repository with name 'r3' does not exist in the registry with id '025416187662'

